# Is it possible to use the MVVMLight framework in a project targeting .NetStandard 1.4?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, .net-standard

I'm new in the Xamarin world and I need to create a Xamarin.Forms project. For the MVVM framework, I'd like to use MVVMLight. The target framework for the Xamarin project will be.NetStandard 1.4 imports portable-net46

I was able to create a simple Xamarin.Forms project running in .NetStandard following [this](https://xamarinhelp.com/dot-net-standard-pcl-xamarin-forms/) guide.

My questions are:

- Is it possible to use the MVVMLight framework in a project targeting
  .NetStandard?
- Does somebody has done that?

Comment: Did you... try it?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, none of the MVVM Light packages is compatible with .NETStandard, Version=v1.4

Answer (score 0):

With VS2015 (json-Projectfile) it may work. Under VS2017 i doesn't get a running solution. All libraries I get under VS2017 to run have an Dependency-Entry ".NETStandard" (MVVM Light hasn't one).